# Chart not being displayed using DotNet.HighCharts and WebForms

Tags: c#, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I'm following this tutorial that discusses databinding to a sql server with WebForms. I've entered raw data to show the charts are working before adding the databinding. However, no chart is being displayed when I run the project. I added DotNet.HighCharts using NuGet in VS2012. Any idea why the chart is not being rendered?
Here's the code for my Default.aspx.cs

```
namespace HighChartsWebForms
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Render_Chart();
        }

        protected void Render_Chart()
        {
            Object[] chartValues = new Object[8]; // declare an object for the chart rendering

            DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")
                .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Line })
                .SetTitle(new Title
                {
                    Text = "Data",
                    X = -20
                })
                .SetSubtitle(new Subtitle
                {
                    Text = "Source: Static data",
                    X = -20
                })
                .SetXAxis(new XAxis
                {
                    Categories = new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug" }
                })
                .SetSeries(new[]
                {
                    new Series
                    {
                        Name = "# Pizza",
                        Data = new Data(new object[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 8 }),
                    },
                });

    ltChart1.Text = chart.ToHtmlString();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="HighChartsWebForms._Default" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1><%: Title %>.</h1>
                <h2>Testing HighCharts with ASP.NET</h2>
            </hgroup>
        </div>
    </section>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h3>This should show a chart:</h3>
    <asp:Literal id="ltChart1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the tutorial I'm following: http://www.balsamino.com/component/k2/item/20-highcharts-databinding-in-c

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **Site.Master** file to add path of the JavaScript files, then make sure you have added path of these three JavaScript files.

```
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>               
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/highcharts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" />   
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/exporting.js" />              
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Check out this tutorial: http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/
Here it is explained for both MVC and Web Forms.

Answer (score 0):

The solution it simple. You have forgotten to import the highcharts.js and ajax libraries.

```
    <asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1><%: Title %>.</h1>
                <h2>Testing HighCharts with ASP.NET</h2>
            </hgroup>
        </div>
    </section>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h3>This should show a chart:</h3>

  <!-- IMPORT THE JAVASCRIPT LIBRARIES HERE -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

  <asp:Literal id="ltChart1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</asp:Content>
```